# Rendering a datagrid with dynamic columns in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface, ria

I have a datagrid which displays details for a product. For a particular product i need to display its Id current status(Available/ Not) and which category it belongs to. The category part is a bit different from what it seems to be like.

Product A can belong to Category A, B and C while product B belongs A ,c and D and so on. Structure of this table would be something like

[image]

The category columns are retrieved from database and passed as parameter to construct the columns dynamically in Datagrid.

I have defined the following Datastructure on UI to handle this.

```
Product{
var productId:String;
var productName:String;
var status:String;
var categoryList:ArrayCollection;
}
```

I am not sure if this will be able to solve my problem.
I think I will need to have a Map containing category Names and if it is applicable for that product.

Any pointers on how to get this datagrid rendered would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case to solve your problem, you gonna need to create another Datastructure:

```
Category{
 var id:Number;
 var name:String;
}
```

After that you will need to extend DataGridColumn. Add “category” property to it.
Generating columns will be like this:

```
for each(var category:Categoty in categories){
 var column:CategoryDataGridColumn = new CategoryDataGridColumn();
 column.category = category;
 column.itemRenderer = CategoryItemRenderer;
 datagrid.columns.push(column);
}
```

CategoryItemRenderer will extend basic DataGrid Item Renderer. Will have something like this:

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
{
 super.commitProperties();
 if(_dataChanged)
 {
  _dataChanged = false;
  text = getText();
 }
}

private function getText():String
{
 var result:String = “Not Belongs”
 var columnCategory:Category = CategoryDataGridColumn(listData.owner.columns[listData.columnIndex]).category;
 for each(var category:Category in Product(data).categoriesList)
 {
  if(columnCategory.id == category.id)
  {
   result = “Belongs”;
   break;
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```